# Is a divisible module over a local principal ideal domain a torsion module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, injective-module

Is an injective module over a local principal ideal domain a torsion module?
We know that injective modules and divisible modules over a PID are equivalent. What do we say about the torsion submodule of such a module, in general?
Thank you.

Comment: We know that injective modules and divisible modules over a PID are equivalent. What do we say about the torsion submodule of such a module, in general? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Injective modules over noetherian rings are classified, this was done by Matlis in his [famous paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1958/8-3/p13.xhtml). Over a local PID $R$ the classification gets very easy, any injective module is of the form $\bigoplus\limits_{j} Q \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{i} Q/R$, where $Q$ is the fraction field of $R$.

The torsion submodule is of course equal to $\bigoplus\limits_{i} Q/R$.